# I need rewrite .htaccess url old to new help me

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've changed my url a wordpress, however I am with some errors.

With some images and post ajax. My new url : `http://practicetends.tempsite.ws/` but I have much images with domain is www.practicetends.com.br Url old : www.praticetends.com.br I need redirect posts ajax and images to url new... I try url rewrite but not work for me!!! I tried it but it didn't work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^practicetends.com.br$
RewriteRule (.*) http://practicetends.tempsite.ws/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work. You could make it work, if the domain is pointing to the same server / virtual host. I suggest you do a search and replace of the old URL to the new URL using this https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/.

You can do a dry run and see exactly what will get changed.